# why am I getting "is not a function error" for my object method?

Tags: javascript, oop

I am get an "is not a function" error for the following code

```
function menu_item(name,price,description,type){
    this.name=name;
    this.price="$"+price;
    this.description=description;
    this.type=type;
    this.create_item=create_item;
    function create_item(){
        var item_slot=document.createElement('div');
        item_slot.className='item';
        item_slot.id=this.name;
        document.getElementById(this.type).appendChild(item_slot);

        var the_name=document.createTextNode(this.name);
        item_slot.appendChild(the_name);
    }

}

var hamburger=new menu_item("Hamburger",4.55,"A 6oz patty burger served on your choice of wheat, white, or rye bun.","burger");
var cheeseburger=new menu_item("Cheeseburger",4.95,"A 6oz patty burger served with American,Mozzarella, or Provolone cheese on your choice of wheat, white, or rye bun.","burger");
var bacon_hamburger=new menu_item("Bacon Hamburger",5.65,"A 6oz patty burger and honey glazed bacon served on your choice of wheat, white, or rye bun.","burger");
var bacon_cheeseburger=new menu_item("Hamburger",5.90,"A 6oz patty burger,topped with honey glazed bacon served with American,Mozzarella, or Provolone cheese on your choice of wheat, white, or rye bun.","burger");
//wings
var chicken_wings=new menu_item("Chicken Wings(6)",4.55,"A basket of 6 crispy chicken wings in your choice of bbq,hot,mild, or tangy sauce.","wings");
//fries
var fries=new menu_item("Freedom Fries",1.50,"A 1/2 pound of crispy golden fries.","fries");
var gravy_fries=new menu_item("Gravy Fries",2.50,"A 1/2 pound of freedom fries slathered in gravy and melted cheese.","fries");
//desert
var cheesecake=new menu_item("Cheese Cake",2.00,"Top off you meal with a slice of our signature cheese cake","desert");
var oreocake=new menu_item("Oreo Cake",2.00,"A delectable oreo cheese cake complements any meal well","desert");
var chocolatechip_cookies=new menu_item("Chocolate Chip Cookies",1.50,"A bag of five chocolate chip cookies are always a favorite with the kids.","desert");
//drinks
var drinks=new menu_item("Drinks", 1.00, "16 oz drink of your choice of apple,grape,lemon, or orange soda","drinks");



//various objects created that are then put into array below vv    
    var food_array=[hamburger,cheeseburger,bacon_cheeseburger,bacon_hamburger,chicken_wings,fries,gravy_fries,cheesecake,oreocake,chocolatechip_cookies,drinks];

function populate_menu(){
    for(var x in food_array){
        x.create_item();
    }
}
```

the populate_menu function is then executed onload in the html, but I am getting errors...can anybody explain why this is happening?

Comment: Show the code please where you define the variables hamburger, cheeseburger.. etc.

Comment: Are you sure those objects are correctly being set to `new menu_item(...)`? That syntax should work given every one of the array elements is actually type menu_item (and even if one isn't being set correctly it will give you that error).

Comment: need to learn about `scope`. Can't call `create_item` where it isn't in scope

Comment: @charlietfl That's not the problem. The Function Declaration statement is hoisted and is bound to the item/object via `this.create_item=create_item`, where it is later (*if* everything else went correctly) invoked as `x.create_item()`.

Comment: You might want to filter out the properties found on the prototype chain by adding `food_array.hasOwnProperty(x)` to the body of `for`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is that `for(var x in obj)` [iterates *all* Enumerable *properties* in `obj`](http://es5.github.io/#x12.6.4) (in an *undefined order*). As such, for-in is *not suitable* for iterating an array as a sequence of items.

I suspect the code is running into this issue and finding a "non menu_item" object which does not have a "create_item" method; instead, iterate an Array with a loop like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var item = arr[i];
  // ..
}
```

Or, alternatively, with [Array.prototype.forEach in ES5](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.18):

```
arr.forEach(function (item) {
   // ..
});
```

Comment: Thankyou this made me remember the detail I forgot "food_array[x].create_item()"

Comment: @FrankieDee Doh, I missed the trees for the forest! However, also take time to *switch* the code to *not* use for-in for this task.